# Grouping and displaying records per day in ASP.NET repeater

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

In a records repeater where database table has multiple votes for each choice in specific day, how can I bind / group records to be displayed for the last week days and each day votes appear separately or where to start to list the last 7 days before current day. can I do this only with stored procedure or there are code required?

I'm using the following Repeater, Code and Stored Procedure which only returns a record per day.

## Repeater

```
<asp:Repeater id="rpHistory" Runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3">
        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "WeekDay")%> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Date")%>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "VoteCount")%>
     </div>
      </div>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

## Code

```
Dim drHistory As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
objDB.cmdGetOnlineChoiceHistory.Parameters("@iChoiceID").Value = Request("ChoiceID")
objDB.Conn.Open()
drHistory = objDB.cmdGetOnlineChoiceHistory.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
rpHistory.DataSource = drHistory
rpHistory.DataBind()
drHistory.Close()
objDB.Conn.Close()
```

## Stored Procedure

```
@iChoiceID int
As
Begin
SELECT top 7 count(CV.Created) as VoteCount, CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), CV.Created, 101) as Date, DATENAME(weekday, CV.Created) as WeekDay from AVSBL_CategoryVotes CV group by CV.Created 
order by CV.Created desc
End
```

## Image

[image: Current and target outpot]

[image: Database table]

## UPDATE

For some reason the day format in "Created" Column and any convert in grouping didn't work. Since I needed the Created Column, I have added a column for DateDay with **DEFAULT (CONVERT([varchar],getdate(),(112)))** and used it instead.

```
@iChoiceID int
As
Begin
SELECT TOP 7 count(CV.Day) AS VoteCount, CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), 
CV.Day, 101) AS Date, 
DATENAME(weekday, CV.Day) AS WeekDay 
FROM AVSBL_CategoryVotes CV GROUP BY CV.Day 
ORDER BY CV.Day DESC
End
```

[image]

Comment: Do the grouping in your query itself.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul I tried many ways but couldn't reach actually

Comment: Your query should work fine. Show your table structure with some sample data.

Comment: I have uploaded an image for the DB table .. doesn't work .. could difference in names "as Date" and "Created" cause that? I changed but didn't .. will try no convert

Comment: Since I needed te Created Column, I have added a column for DateDay with DEFAULT (CONVERT([varchar],getdate(),(112))) and used it instead .. it works fine now

Answer (score 0):

Try like below. Instead of `group by` on `created` column; try doing a `group by` on the converted date column `group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), Created, 101)`

```
SELECT top 7 count(Created) as VoteCount, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), Created, 101) as [Date], 
DATENAME(weekday, Created) as [WeekDay]
from AVSBL_CategoryVotes 
group by CAST(Created AS DATE) 
order by Created desc
```

Comment: Yes I tried but SQL 2008 returns "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'."

Comment: Column 'AVSBL_CategoryVotes.Created' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: now when I changed all dates in records to 00:00:00 and used simple created without convert it worked .. if I used convert it doesn't

Comment: created is a datetime column and so grouping will not work properly. You will have to get the date part and then do the grouping. Try the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all you calculations and groupings are based on the reduced date only part.

```
SELECT top 7 count(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), Created, 101) ) as VoteCount, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), Created, 101) as [Date], 
DATENAME(weekday, count(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), Created, 101))) as [WeekDay]
from  AVSBL_CategoryVotes 
group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), Created, 101) 
order by count(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), Created, 101) ) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
SELECT TOP 7 Count(CONVERT(DATE, Created))             AS [VoteCount],
             CONVERT(DATE, Created)                    AS [Date],
             Datename(weekday, CONVERT(DATE, Created)) AS [WeekDay]
FROM   AVSBL_CategoryVotes
GROUP  BY CONVERT(DATE, Created)
ORDER  BY CONVERT(DATE, Created) DESC
```